# Finding all elements containing a string with XPath in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, xpath

I'm trying to get all elements containing a string:

```
function getElementsByText( text, ctx) {
  return document.evaluate(
      "//*[.='"+text+"']", 
      ctx || document,
      null,
      XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE,
      null
    ).iterateNext();
}

var searchString = "Name";
var parents = getElementsByText(searchString);

for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
  parents[i].style.opacity = .2;
};
```

The docs say [`evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) with `ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE` returns "all the nodes matching the expression". But `getElementsByText` returns only the first occurrence.

This code doesn't work because `parents` is not iterable.

How can I get all the elements?

Comment: check out this example http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/kjD8r/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call the `evaluate` method you will get an https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathResult on which you need to call `iterateNext` as long as you want the next node of the selected nodeset. If you want to have an array then do e.g.

```
function getElementsByText( text, ctx) {
  var results = [];
  var xpathResult = document.evaluate(
      "//*[.='"+text+"']", 
      ctx || document,
      null,
      XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE,
      null
    );
   var node;
   while ((node = xpathResult.iterateNext()) != null) {
     results.push(node);
   }
   return results;
}
```